# C++ resolving istream::tellg warning

Tags: c++

Warning:

```
warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'std::streamoff' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
```

Caused by:

```
unsigned int FileSize = File.tellg( ); // WARNING
std::cout << "Size = " << FileSize << std::endl;
```

Possible solution?
Is it okay to do this:

```
// No more warnings but, is it safe?
unsigned int FileSize = (unsigned int)File.tellg( ); // OK?
std::cout << "Size = " << FileSize << std::endl;
```

How about this?

```
// No more warnings but, is it safe?
unsigned int FileSize = static_cast< unsigned int >( File.tellg( ) );
```

Comment: Both solutions are fine. [I suggest you read up on casts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want `std::streamoff FileSize = File.tellg();`?

Comment: Yes both are fine as Cornstalks says - tellg() returns a streampos, which supports conversion to integer.

Comment: @nobar I am initializing a vector so I need to set the size.

Comment: It is fine only is you know *for sure* that the file will never be larger than what an `int` can hold. The warning is there because `std::streamoff` *can* hold larger values. You are not resolving the warning, but telling the compiler to shut up.

Comment: Also, I just want to let you know that if you don't open the file in binary mode, `tellg()`

Comment: 1. (unsigned int)()
2. static_cast< unsigned int >()
Both solution do similar work. 1. C casting. 2. C++ casting.
C++ style casts are checked by the compiler. C style casts aren't and can fail at runtime.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`streamoff` is a signed integral type defined by your C++ standard library implementation, and large enough to cater for the largest possible file sizes. In my x86_64 stdlibc++ for example, it is a `int64_t`.

In order to avoid potential data loss, use a larger type or... simply let your variable be of type `streamoff`.

Comment: I am trying to initialize the size of a vector. Which means, the size can't be negative and steamoff can handle negative and positive integers.

Comment: If *your* streamoff variable can actually be negative, then you have to *check* for that condition in your code. Simply casting your negative signed value to an unsigned one will always cause problems.