# Visual c++ is this unsafe conversion between std::ifstream::pos_type and size_t?

Tags: c++11, integer, type-conversion, compiler-warnings

My compiler complains about possible data loss when I assign as follows:

```
size_t* size = new size_t;
std::ifstream::pos_type fileSize = file.tellg();//This works fine

char* fileContents = new char[fileSize];//Warning 1
*size = fileSize;//Warning 2
```

Warnings below:

```
Warning 1   warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'std::streamoff' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data.
Warning 2   warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'std::streamoff' to 'size_t', possible loss of data.
```

So is there a way to safely convert variable from type `std::ifstream::pos_type` to `size_t`.
I could just be rude and tell the compiler to keep quiet about this by using explicit c style casting, but I wonder if it is safe?

My code compiles and runs correctly, but as value in `fileSize` grows when bigger files are read this could break right?
Is this the unsafe way to get the file size and is there any better approach to this?

Comment: Three problems that I see as an old C++ programmer: No need to create simple variables (or barely anything) dynamically using pointers and `new` (do you come from a Java background?); Don't use `malloc` when allocating memory; And avoid allocating dynamically to begin with (use e.g. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)).

Comment: As for your problem, it's most likely because of the use of the non-standard `SIZE_T` type. Try using the standard `off_t` (for offsets), `size_t` or possibly what the compiler tells you the type is(`pos_type`).

Comment: And just to nit-pick, please don't post the error message in the code snippet, post the *complete* error log in the question body and *mark* the line (or lines) referenced by the message(s) in some other way.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Do you suggest creating a vector with the data in it? PS: I started my programming career with java and C.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I switched to standard `size_t`

Comment: It kind of depends on what the data is. Is it a string or text-only data? Then use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Is it arbitrary binary bytes without structure? Then `std::vector` is a good candidate, but so is `std::string` as well.  If the data in the file is structured, then one or more structures will be good, or a vector of structures.

Comment: It appears that `std::ifstream::pos_type` is a 64-bit integer (files could be larger than 4GB even on 32-bit systems), while `size_t` is a 32-bit integer. If you are sure the file you work with is small enough, just cast the return value of `tellg` down to `size_t`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ resolving istream::tellg warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172315/c-resolving-istreamtellg-warning)